# Autoload .obj.php files in Zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am using a custom scheme in naming my files. Any pointers on how to autoload them with Zend's autoloader?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write your own autoloader class and register it with the ZF autoloader. There is a brief bit about this in the manual: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader.html#zend.loader.autoloader.interface

Basically it's just a class defining one method which takes the class name as the parameter. So for you it would be something like:

```
class My_Autoloader implements Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Interface
{
    public function autoload($class)
    {
        $filename = $class.'.obj.php';
        require $filename;
    }
}
```

the above assumes the classes are on the include path, if not, just stick the full path in front of $filename. Add any other mapping/checking you need in here and then register it as per the example in the manual. Normally you would do this in your bootstrap.